# How to gain an understanding of Material Science topics?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, python

I am a high schooler and a part-time programmer. I want to become a material scientist. I am looking for a gentle introduction to Material Modelling and Materials Science, preferably at a high school or undergraduate level.

Comment: I cant help with an answer directly, but find my email and email me.  I was close to your position at one point and would be happy to point you in the right direction.

Comment: What sub-field of material science are you interested in? For example, superconductivity? Soft materials? Hydrogen storage? Catalysts? Solar cells? Structural materials?

Comment: Similar question [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/141/24)

Comment: @TristanMaxson Thanks for such nice courage, I would love to have someone guide me in the right direction. Can you share your email?

Comment: @wzkchem5 It might be too ambitious, but in terms of interest. I get excited about quantum materials ( fiction ), to be real I think the super conductive materials are kinda cool

Comment: its tgmaxson at gmail

Comment: @Mechtron28 (cool name by the way, especially if it stands for "mechatronics", a term sometimes used for a field that's a combination of mechanical and electrical engineering), I was considering to write an answer to this question, and that's why I voted to leave the question open, but when I noticed that Tyberius hammered the question closed, it did occur to me that you haven't visited the site in 8 months (and the question was asked 8 months ago), so even if I spend an hour writing a thorough and detailed answer for you, there's a big risk that you'll never see it. **If you do see this,**

Comment: **then let us know so that we can reopen the question for you**. Right now it's basically not worth it because we don't know if you'll see the message or not.